# Manual addition of namespace to XElements fails upon validation

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

I was attempting to validate a group of XML tags that I have with an xsd file that I created, *with the added constraint that all `XElement`'s must belong to a namespace.*

```
<xs:schema id="TestSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://test.org/test.xsd"
  xmlns="http://test.org/test.xsd"
  xmlns:mstns="http://test.org/test.xsd"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  >

<xs:element name="testRoot">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="testObject">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo" />
            <xs:element name="bar" />
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="testType" type="xs:int" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

/xs:schema>
```

... where the XML that I start with appears as follows:

```
<testRoot>
  <testObject testType="2">
    <foo />
    <bar />
  </testObject>
</testRoot>
```

Any problems that may stem from the syntax of the element declarations is because this is simplified; interestingly, **the XML validates against this schema when I don't bother trying to add namespaces to the elements.**

Once the XML is parsed into LINQ to XML, I add namespaces to each element with an extension method:

```
public static void SetDefaultXmlNamespace(this XElement element, XNamespace ns)
{
    foreach (var item in element.DescendantsAndSelf())
    {
        item.Name = ns.GetName(item.Name.LocalName);
    }
}
```

But my attempts to validate this schema are unsuccessful. Attempting to create and validate against the above XML yields a cryptic error:

`The element 'testRoot' in namespace 'http://test.org/test.xsd' has invalid child element 'testObject' in namespace 'http://test.org/test.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'testObject'.`

I would expect such a simple example to succeed, but I'm clearly missing something.

I attempt the validation by converting the XElement tree in question into an XDocument and then validating:

```
string xsdMarkup = "schema here";
XElement testRoot; // declared elsewhere
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(AppStateXmlMapper.SchemaNamespace, XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));

XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(testRoot);
xmlDoc.Root.SetDefaultXmlNamespace(AppStateXmlMapper.Ns);
List<string> errorList = new List<string>();

// attempt validation
xmlDoc.Validate(schemas, (sender, args) =>
{
    errorList.Add(args.Message);
});
```

It's probably worth noting that I've tried adding constraints to the schema such as the `elementFormDefault= "qualified"` and `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` tag, but that simply changes the validation errors to other elements/attributes. I tried adding a namespace to every single attribute on the fly as well, but the validation issues persist. I'm sure the problem is in my xsd file somewhere, but I have no idea what that issue is. Any thoughts on my problem would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

When adding `elementFormDefault= "qualified"` to my schema, the validation errors change, to: `The 'testType' attribute is not declared.`, and the accompanying error: `The required attribute 'http://test.org/test.xsd:testType' is missing.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is indeed due to namespace qualification, I do not know LINQ but it seems that the error:

`The element 'testRoot' in namespace 'http://test.org/test.xsd' has nvalid 
child element 'testObject' in namespace 'http://test.org/test.xsd'. List 
of possible elements expected: 'testObject'`

means the validator expects 'testObject' to be in no namespace while it received it in the 'http://test.org/test.xsd' namespace.

[ElementFormDefault](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref50) is by default `unqualified`, so that means the root of your schema needs the namespace qualification but that the sub-elements do not need it.

Considering both `elementFormDefault` and `attributeFormDefault` not set or set to `unqualified`, a valid XML instance of the schema above would be:

```
<tns:testRoot xmlns:tns="http://test.org/test.xsd">
  <testObject testType="2">
    <foo />
    <bar />
  </testObject>
</tns:testRoot>
```

So you should not add namespace to each element but only to the root one.

Let me know if I am not correct.

Comment: I would normally agree with you, because that logically makes sense, but I get validation errors on attributes when I add  `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the xsd file. See my follow-up edit :(

Comment: Additionally, I would normally agree with you that the above schema and leaving `FormDefault` attributes to `unqualified` should validate correctly, but the same validation errors happen as in my follow-up edit. Finally, I am constrained in that all the sub-elements must contain the namespace, so my code for appending namespaces to all sub-elements is theoretically what is desired.

Comment: What if you explicitly declare attributeFormDefault='unqualified' ? Otherwise someone more experienced with LINQ might know what's happening here.. :-/

Comment: This did end up being the issue. Thanks for the help!